# What should I do with Kohana 3 to make route actions' hyphens change to underscores?

Tags: php, routes, kohana-3

Consider this route in `bootstrap.php`...

```
Route::set('crud', 'staff/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))', array(
            'controller' => '(activities|users|default-emails)',
            'action' => '(new|view|modify|delete)',
            'id' => '\d+'
    ))->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'staff',
        'action' => 'view'
    ));
```

The `default-emails` is trying to run the `action_default-emails()` method which obviously doesn't and can't exist.

What part of Kohana should I extend to map that hyphen into a underscore internally?

Should I be concerned that if I do do this, then it will be accessible via both `_` and `-` delimited routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to hack `Kohana_Request::execute()@1112`

```
$class->getMethod('action_'.$action)->invokeArgs($controller, $this->_params);
```

change to

```
$class->getMethod('action_'.str_replace('-', '_', $action))->invokeArgs($controller, $this->_params);
```

But you understand, that you have to do this patch in each next kohana version.

More harmless could be to extend `Kohana_Route::matches()`

```
class Route extends Kohana_Route
{
    public function matches($uri)
    {
        $matches = parent::matches($uri);
        if (isset($matches['action']))
        {
            $matches['action'] = str_replace('-', '_', $matches['action'];
        }
        return $matches;
    }
}
```

Did not check, but I bet it should work.

Comment: Thanks zerkms - I may submit a feature request later.

Comment: @alex: it will be rejected, 100% ;-)

Comment: @alex: another way - to extend "Kohana_Controller" and create `__call()`, that handles such cases.

Comment: Oh yeah - I've often wondered how do I do a 2 word controller `like_this` when the underscore maps to directory separator.

Comment: Just wondering - lambda routes in KO 3.1 will solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

My solution for Kohana 3.2 for routing hyphenated actions to the appropriate underscored method:
Extend Kohana_Route and insert this code

```
if($key == 'action')
{
    $params[$key] = str_replace('-','_',$value);
}
else
{
    $params[$key] = $value;
}
```

**Full Solution:** Create a file route.php in application/classes/

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Route extends Kohana_Route
{
    public function matches($uri)
    {
        if ($this->_callback)
        {
            $closure = $this->_callback;
            $params = call_user_func($closure, $uri);

            if ( ! is_array($params))
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( ! preg_match($this->_route_regex, $uri, $matches))
                return FALSE;

            $params = array();
            foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_int($key))
                {
                    // Skip all unnamed keys
                    continue;
                }

                // Set the value for all matched keys
                                if($key == 'action')
                                {
                                    $params[$key] = str_replace('-','_',$value);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $params[$key] = $value;
                                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($this->_defaults as $key => $value)
        {
            if ( ! isset($params[$key]) OR $params[$key] === '')
            {
                // Set default values for any key that was not matched
                $params[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $params;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest way I have ever seen this done, including being better for my needs than the solutions proposed by the Kohana core team (I'm not a fan of having to put a regex or callback into every single route to achieve what can be easily done with an extended class). I had to make some modifications to get it to work with Kohana 3.3, but the _approach_ of extending the class and tweaking the matching function works great.

Answer (score 3):

Since Kohana 3.3 came out this method no longer works.  I have found a solution that, so far, works for me.

When upgrading to 3.3, you don't need to edit the Internal.php request file.  Instead, you can create a Route Filter.  All you need to do is replace hyphen in the action to an underscore.

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->filter(function($route, $params, $request) {
        // Replacing the hyphens for underscores.
        $params['action'] = str_replace('-', '_', $params['action']);
        return $params; // Returning an array will replace the parameters.
    })
    ->defaults(array(
         'controller' => 'welcome',
         'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

This obviously only works for the methods. However, if you explore a little further, you can create a better function for the directory, controller, etc.

Answer (score 1):

An update to zerkms's method. In **Kohana 3.2**, you need to edit the file `system/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php` **line 106**.

Replace:

```
$action = $request->action();
```

By:

```
$action = str_replace('-', '_', $request->action());
```

I dislike hacking frameworks but this is by far the simplest and most reliable solution. Renaming the action in the Route class can lead to all sorts of troubles, because the action will then sometime be called my_action (internally) and sometime my-action (in links).